# Как удалить массив из многомерного массива?

Tags: php, массивы, foreach

Есть массив items. В нем массивы, содержащие значения fbo и fbs могут располагаться в разных порядках [0] или [1]:

```
Array (
[0] => Array (
    [product_id] => 111
    [offer_id] => AR-001
    [stocks] => Array (
        [0] => Array (
            [type] => fbo
            [present] => 0
            [reserved] => 0
            )
        [1] => Array (
            [type] => fbs
            [present] => 10
            [reserved] => 0
            )
        )
    )
[1] => Array (
    [product_id] => 222
    [offer_id] => AR-002
    [stocks] => Array (
        [0] => Array (
            [type] => fbs
            [present] => 0
            [reserved] => 0
            )
        [1] => Array (
            [type] => fbo
            [present] => 20
            [reserved] => 0
            )
        )
    )
)
```

В цикле foreach хочу удалить внутренние массивы, где есть fbo. Чтобы на выходе получился массив, содержащий только fbs. Вот так:

```
Array (
[0] => Array (
    [product_id] => 111
    [offer_id] => AR-001
    [stocks] => Array (
        [0] => Array (
            [type] => fbs
            [present] => 10
            [reserved] => 0
            )
        )
    )
[1] => Array (
    [product_id] => 222
    [offer_id] => AR-002
    [stocks] => Array (
        [0] => Array (
            [type] => fbs
            [present] => 0
            [reserved] => 0
            )
         )
    )
)
```

Пробую так:

```
 foreach ($items as $k => $v) {
  if ($v['stocks']['type'] == 'fbo') {
        unset($items[$k]);
    }
```

Но так не удаляется.

Как это можно сделать? Подскажите, пожалуйста. Желательно пример кода.

Сделала вот так:

```
$stocks = [
'stocks' => []  // в массиве $stocks создаем один элемент
];

foreach ($items as $itemIndex=>$item) {

    foreach($item['stocks'] as $stockIndex=>$stock) {
        if ($stock['type'] === "fbo") {
            unset($items[$itemIndex]['stocks'][$stockIndex]);
        }
    }
$stocks['stocks'][] = [
'offer_id'  =>  $item['offer_id'],
'stock' => $item['stocks'][1]['present'],
'warehouse_id' => '2222',
];
}

print_r($stocks);
```

Это работает, теперь остались только fbs. Но возникла другая проблема.
Хочу поместить результат в массив stocks. Но на выходе получаю:

```
Array ( [stocks] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [offer_id] => AR-001 [stock] => 50 [warehouse_id] => 2222 )[1] => Array ( [offer_id] => AR-002 [stock] => 0 [warehouse_id] => 2222 ) ) )
```

Т.е. значения [stock] не верны. Там, где 0 должно быть количество, там где 10 должен быть 0. Что делаю не так?

Comment: Приведите пример кода,  где у вас возникает проблема. Тут не пишут код за вас

Comment: foreach ($items as $k => $v) {
  if ($v['stocks']['type'] == 'fbo') {
        unset($items[$k]);
    }

Comment: вам вложенный цикл написать надо по `$v['stocks']`

Comment: Сделала вот так: foreach ($items as $k => $v) {
   foreach ($v['stocks'] as $a){
if($a['type'] == 'fbo'){
 unset($a); 
}
}
} Массивы, содержащие значение fbo удалились, но а как теперь новые данные записать в items?

Comment: foreach ($items as $k => $v) { foreach ($v['stocks'] as $a){ if($a['type'] == 'fbo'){ unset($items[$k]); continue 2; } } }

Comment: добавить ключи во втором цикле и сделать `unset($items[$k][$idx])`